# 四隅に四角形がない、 QR コードようなこれは何?

Tags: untagged

今日、街中を歩いていたら次のような qr コードのようなものを見つけました。

[image: qr コード without 四隅の四角形]

QR コードっぽいのですが、四隅に四角形がないので、多分仕様としては QR コードではなさそうだ、と思っています。

#### 質問

- 上記のような qr コードっぽいものは一体何ですか?

Comment: 四隅は四角ではありませんが、よく見ると向きが一意に決まるようになっている(この写真だと左下だけ閉じてる)のはQRコードと同じようですね。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SPコード](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/SP%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89)です。
質問の画像のコードには2行程度のテキストが11の言語で含まれていました。

中国語の部分:

> 於夜間穿越行人穿越道時 請按下按鈕
>   為保障您的安全 敬請遵守交通號誌
>
> > google翻訳: 
> >     夜に横断歩道を横断するときにボタンを押す
> >     安全を守るために、交通標識に従ってください

利用例として、個人番号通知の封筒と通知カード（の台紙？）に印刷されていたものがあります。
QRコードがカメラの端にでも入ればすぐに認識される一方、このSPコードはもう少し正確にカメラを合わせる必要があり、視覚障害者向けとして機能していたかは疑問です。

#### 商標・特許

「SPコード」は登録商標のようで、これを避けるために一部では「音声コード」や「Uni-Voice」と呼ばれています。
ただし、

> 「SPコード」および「スピーチオ」に関する権利は、（株）廣済堂と（株）オリジナルデザインが共同出願した特許第3499220号、特許第4439756号、特許第4744745号および特許第4772631号保護されています。
>   http://www.sp-code.com/index.html

との事で、「音声コード」などと呼ばれているものでも、自由に使える実装などは無さそうです。

#### 参考

関連団体:

- [SPコード公式ホームページ](http://www.sp-code.com/index.html)
- [日本視覚障がい情報普及支援協会](http://www.javis.jp/index.php)
- [Uni-Voice事業企画株式会社](http://uni-voice.co.jp/)

報道:

- [押しボタン式信号機、15言語対応に　警視庁](https://www.nikkei.com/article/DGXLASDG09H0Q_Z01C16A2CN0000/)
- [信号表示を多言語対応へ　押しボタン式、警視庁](http://www.sankei.com/photo/daily/news/161209/dly1612090008-n1.html)
- [＜音声コード・ユニボイス＞手話や音声、多言語に対応−−らくらくホンやｉＰｈｏｎｅで…](http://mainichi.jp/universalon/articles/20140930/mog/00m/040/030000c)

Comment: オープンソースのライブラリはあるのでしょうか？なんだか典型的な日本の公共事業の臭いがします...

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi オープンソースなどのエコシステムは皆無ですね。オリンピックに向けて設置を増やしていくなどという話もあるようです……